# ¿Cómo separar en una columna de fechas de tipo str solamente el año?

Tags: python, string, pandas, date, split

Tengo un DataFrame con una columna con fechas de tipo `object` y tengo que crear una columna que solo muestre los años. La columna tiene este formato:

```
   date

0  2019-06-08
1  2019-06-08
2  2019-06-04
...
```

cuando la he separado usando `str.split("-")` me ha quedado dividido como en sublistas, de esta forma:

```
0       [2019, 06, 08]
1       [2019, 06, 08]
2       [2019, 06, 08]
```

entonces al intentar elegir solo la primera parte de esas sablistas haciendo `df[:,0]` o usando `axis`, me salta un error por que cada lista es única. Tambien he probado el parámetro `maxsplit` pero me salta error. ¿Cómo podría elegir esa primera parte de todas las listas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero aclarar que el argumento `maxsplit` no existe en `pandas.Series.str.split`, su nombre es `n`. No soluciona el problema, pero por eficiencia se puede usar.

Simplemente vuelve a usar  `pandas.Series.str` sobre la salida de `pandas.Series.str.split` para permitir que se indice de forma vectorizada:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ("2019-06-08", "2019-06-08", "2020-06-07")})
```

> ```
> >>> df
>          date
> 0  2019-06-08
> 1  2019-06-08
> 2  2020-06-07
> ```

```
df.date = df.date.str.split("-", n=1).str[0]
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    date
> 0  2019
> 1  2019
> 2  2020
> ```

Aunque sería más directo usar un slicing sin más si tu formato es siempre `yyyy-*`:

```
df.date = df.date.str[:4]
```

Si quieres también convertir a entero, aplica `pandas.Series.astype`:

```
df.date = df.date.str[:4].astype("int")
```